# broadcast numpy difference to a third dimension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Setup

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])
B = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3]])

A

array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])

B

array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [4, 3]])
```

I need to take the difference of the first row of `A` with each row of `B`.  If I do:

```
A - B[0]

array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

I just need this for each row of B.

A non-vectorized approach is:

```
np.array([A - B[i] for i in range(B.shape[0])])

array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 1,  2]],

       [[-1,  0],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[-3, -1],
        [-2,  0]]])
```

## Question

What is a vectorized approach to get the same 3-dimensional array?  I'm ok with using pandas if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a dimension to your `B` array for `numpy` to properly broadcast it:

```
In [15]: A - B[:, np.newaxis]
Out[15]:
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 1,  2]],

       [[-1,  0],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[-3, -1],
        [-2,  0]]])
```

Comment: To help figure out how the array dimensions are extended it may be worth noting that in this example ``B[:, np.newaxis]`` equivals to ``B[:, np.newaxis, :]``